# Advanced search with multi-combination-AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I'm having three different input boxes as labelled below:

First Name

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="firstName" / >
```

Last Name

```
<input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="lastName" / >
```

Roll Number

```
<input type="text" name="roll Number" ng-model="rNumber" / >
```

and a Search button to search different combinations based on the input..

```
<button type="button" ng-click="search()">Search</button>
```

In the Controller:

```
 $scope.search=function(){
    if($scope.firstName){      //1st case
    //search operation
      }

 if($scope.lastName){    //2nd case
    //search operation
      }    

 if($scope.lastName && $scope.firstName){    // 3rd case is failing
    //search operation
      }
    }
```

The search gets failed when I try for the third type of search because since $scope.lastName is defined it executes the 2nd case and not the 3rd case which I want to execute.How can I run the 3rd case if my input is both lastName and firstName?

Comment: `if(a && b) {... } else if(a) {... } else if(b) { ...}`

Comment: How does Sergiu's answer not work?  That is the correct logic. Can you post a plunker? if($scope.firstName && $scope.lastName) {... } else if($scope.firstName) {... } else if($scope.lastName) { ...}

Comment: Sorry @jw56578 .Its working .@Sergiu can you post it as an answer please

Comment: @MANOJ, in other words, don't forget about basic programming when using Angular. :) What is there to post as answer?I suggest you delete this question as it has little to do with Angular and is unlikely to benefit future Angular programmers.